# Playing multiple audio files in javascript with help of html

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to play a Background music and many audio files also need to played when the background music is playing.

So how can i get it done with the help of "javascript" and "html" ..

Thanks

Comment: google html + audio api first , then come back with what you tried and why it did not work if it did not.

Comment: Nothing like Google, https://www.google.com/search?q=audio+website+background&aq=f&oq=audio+website+background&aqs=chrome.0.57j0l3j62l2.5283&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following to get started:

```
track1 = new Audio('track1.mp3');
track2 = new Audio('track2.mp3');
track3 = new Audio('track3.mp3');

track1.play();
track2.play();
track3.play();
```

You can start reading about the HTML Audio Spec here: http://html5doctor.com/native-audio-in-the-browser/